# Cannot start Tkinter window in Visual Studio with Python Tools

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tkinter

I am developing using Python Tools for Visual Studio in Visual Studio 2013 community edition on Windows 8.1. My problem is that I am unable to get a Tkinter window to start. I have tried using this code:

```
 from tkinter import * 
 Tk()
```

When I launch this code from IDLE and such, I am able to get a tkinter window, as shown:

[image: tkinter in idle]

However, when I start this in Visual Studio, no Tkinter window appears, only the console window. No error is thrown. Example:

[image: tkinter in vs]

How do I get the Tkinter window to appear when I launch the program in Visual Studio with Python tools?

Edit: Also, when I try to do this from the Python interactive window in VS, this is what I get, with no window appearing:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> Tk()
<tkinter.Tk object at 0x02D81FD0>
```

Comment: This may be due to the tkinter mainloop not starting automatically. Try `root=Tk(); root.mainloop()`

Comment: That doesn't appear to have a different effect.

Comment: I think PTVS uses IPython as its console, so you should be able to run `%gui tk` before running your code to start the Tk event loop.

Comment: Tk() creates what should be a visible window, without a tk event loop.  It can respond to at least some mouse clicks but not to tk bindings and scheduled events.  However, running under other GUIs is a problem.  Idle runs user code is a separate process with minimal no-window Idle code designed to not interfere with user tkinter code.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: without an event loop it won't respond to _any_ events, and it will exit immediately (unless the OP has their own infinite loop somewhere)

Comment: @BryanOakley When a Python program exits, yes, the gui it created disappears.  If you run a file with `-i` (which Idle does), so that python does not exit, or enter code interactively, Tk() creates a visible tk window.  My comment is true, at least on Windows. One may create and place a Button with a command.  Clicking on the now visible button will execute the command.  One may enter text in an entry box.  It may be that some of this is OS specific, due to the use of native widgets that are OS specific.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that you aren't starting the event loop. Without the event loop the program will exit immediately. Try altering your program to look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

The reason you don't need to call mainloop in IDLE is because IDLE does that for you. In all other cases you must call mainloop.