# Tkinter can't even invoke a simple "button"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, anaconda

Started with simple Tkinter lessons, I'm stuck in the case even that simple code doesn't work:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text='button'); b.pack()
```

...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2366, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "/Users/../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2296, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed
```

And can't find the reason why, considering that this code is from [official documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/idle.html?highlight=button#developing-tkinter-applications)

On the other hand, [another code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program) works:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

I have tried to update `tk` from conda: `conda install -c anaconda tk`, but nothing change. Can't figure out why.

Comment: Do not close the window before adding the button.

Comment: May be a stupid question, but are you running that code in IDLE, as the instructions specify? I'm not sure if it means from a file in IDLE or on the IDLE console, but I presume it means the latter.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27580163/5722359) address your  situation?

Comment: If you are using Python's default IDLE then mainloop is not required to run tkinter application however it is good to explicitly define the mainloop as anywhere outside of the IDLE it wont work without it.

Comment: I noticed you are using `anaconda`. There is a very good chance your problem is due to this fact. Anaconda is known to have issues with tkinter due to their custom libraries that fail from time to time.

Comment: @SunBear not exactly.

Comment: @Goyo, yes, this is a stupid mistake. I closed the window after `Tk()`.
That's why in python console apears that error https://imgur.com/i76ExgH

Also, the examples from Jason Briggs [books](https://jasonrbriggs.com/python-for-kids/chapter12/clickable_button1.py.txt) confused me a bit.

Comment: @Mike-SMT yes, I found some issues with Anaconda, that's why I decided to ask about it.

Comment: Would any of you summarize all these issues in answer? I'll marked as resolved.

Comment: @Searge I don't know what you mean by "all these issues", the code is perfectly fine and the only issue is you closing a window and then trying to add a button to it. Something that Briggs did not tell you to do, btw.

Comment: @Goyo plus he also forgot `mainloop()`, or that only `anaconda` problem.
Maybe the answer is: don't close the the `tk` window while you working on IDLE, and add `.mainloop()` after `.pack()` when you using editor?

Comment: @Searge No, the issue can be replicated with any python interpreter and the exception would be raised anyway before the call to `mainloop` So neither anaconda nor `mainloop` are related to this.

Comment: @Goyo ah, ok. But first I've write his script (where is no `mainloop`) on editor.
That's why I go to documentation, then open IDLE and have tried to replicate step by step.
It looks like a trivial problem when you know how it works. I know ツ

Comment: @Goyo I am not sure what you mean by closing the window before the button is added. That should not be possible with the presented code. All the code is ran at init so how can one close the window before the button is added? Even writing this code directly in the interpreter (something most would not do) it still works fine on my end.

Comment: @Mike-SMT on python console, when you write `root = tk.Tk()` will apear empty window.

Comment: @Searge why are you writing the code directly in the console instead of in a `.py` file? That seams like a bad idea for writing up a GUI.

Comment: @Mike-SMT [10 min ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216805/tkinter-cant-even-invoke-a-simple-button?noredirect=1#comment95263791_54216805)
In the nut shell: script won't work on editor, so I desided to figure out why. Step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I was able to reproduce your error is by building the code directly in the IDLE Shell and closing the root window that pops up before creating the button.

[image]

That said it is very odd to write a GUI in the Shell like this. If you do not close the tkinter window the code works fine. However GUI development should be done in the editor in a `.py` file and ran all at once. Simple fix is to not close the root window before everything else in the GUI has been added.

Proper fix is to build you GUI in a `.py` file and then run it.

I am not sure why you are saying that the editor is not working for you. When I copy your exact code it works fine on my end:

[image]

All that said you really do not need to build your code in the Python IDLE. It would be much better to use something like PyCharm or Eclipse/PyDev. Those are my Go to IDE tools.

One thing to note about Python's IDLE is it will not run code from the editor until you have saved the `.py` file.

Though not 100% required in the Python IDLE the `mainloop()` is a requirement for tkinter to work properly. Outside of Python's IDLE most other IDE environments requite the `mainloop()` so it is good practice to always include it.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text='button')
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thnx. If you please, also add, that `.mainloop()` is required after calling `.pack()` function. On this I stumbled when have replicate [example](https://jasonrbriggs.com/python-for-kids/chapter12/clickable_button1.py.txt) from book on editor.

Comment: @Searge `mainloop()` is not requited in Python IDLE. The Python IDLE assumes the mainloop for you. This is not the case in most other IDE's though.

Comment: yes. I mean I started to replicate [that file](https://jasonrbriggs.com/python-for-kids/chapter12/clickable_button1.py.txt) on IDE. And it doesn't work (because mainloop), so I go to the documentation and replicate it on python console, where close that empty window ツ

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add `root.mainloop()` at the end.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text='button'); b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: no, that error apears before `mainloop()`. 
https://imgur.com/i76ExgH

Also, in examples from the book "Python for kids" (where I've start that lessons), there is no `.mainloop()` at all, only `.pack()`
https://jasonrbriggs.com/python-for-kids/chapter12/clickable_button1.py.txt

Comment: yes, it works as script, but I can't even define a variable in IDLE, also, none of examples from Jason Briggs works.